# Google chrome froce async function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backend

I'm a beginner in developpement, and for my personal knowledge I try to make a website in html, css and js.

The website get a random project from Artstation with Axios at a [Json](https://www.artstation.com/random_project.json) and display it on the web page, I have 24 random image generated

I share you the Js code :

```js
const images = document.getElementsByClassName("pic");
const redirect1 = document.getElementsByClassName("redirect1");
const redirect2 = document.getElementsByClassName("redirect2");

randomButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].src = "small_square.png";
        loadImages(i);
    }

});

async function loadImages(i) {
    const response = await axios.get("https://www.artstation.com/random_project.json");
    images[i].src = response.data.cover.smaller_square_image_url;
    redirect1[i].href = response.data.permalink;
    redirect2[i].href = response.data.permalink;
}
```

Don't juge it I know is not verry clean, now I explain my problem, I made the code like that for generate the 24 images simultaneously, the problem is if I not open my console in google chrome he load the function one by one, this is a issue I don't have with firefox

I have made the result in [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItdeC.jpg)
Did you know how fix that ?

Comment: Do you just want all the images to appear at the same time? I mean your code is actually working asynchronously it's just that the responses are coming back in a pretty linear fashion.

Comment: No, I want to images appear when she load the fastet possible, i need to make asynchrone function (wait axios get the json). On video the 2 last video is the good way, and not the fist video, but i don't know why google chrome need to open web console for load all at the same time

So not appear at the same time, but execute the function "loadImages" at the same time